# PySHP tag missing syntax highlighting

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

The [pyshp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyshp) tag is missing the appropriate syntax highlighting setting. It should be set to lang-py.

Comment: @AndreSilva It is, sort of, although only moderators can make this change and I thought that a new question would be more effective in letting them all know, as opposed to just commenting on that question which would just ping PolyGeo.

Comment: No problem, it is your choice. But I think it is beneficial keeping these Qs linked to the canonical one, so people get to know the big picture.

Comment: I have updated the tag to lang-py